# How to 'bundle' referenced FHIR resources on a localhost SPARK server

Tags: reference, localhost, bundle, hl7-fhir

I have SPARK FHIR server setup locally and I've tried all sorts to query (GET) a patient resource that is referenced in Observation, Condition, Immunization etc., so that the resulting bundle contains the index Patient resource as well as all resource instances containing a reference to that Patient resource.
This comes close (online SPARK server):

http://fhir3.healthintersections.com.au/open/Patient/1/$everything

This is what I'm looking for (online HAPI server):

GET http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2/Patient?_id=14676&_revinclude=Immunization:patient&_revinclude=MedicationStatement:patient&_format=xml

Neither works on my localhost SPARK server. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Both the $everything operation and the _revinclude functionality are not implemented on Spark at this time. So other than modifying your own copy of the server, Spark cannot do this for you right now.